# asp.net treeview - how to remove/ hide the root node?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, treeview

i have a asp.net tree view control and its being data bound to XML returned from the DB.
once bound and the nodes are present in the control how can i remove/ hide the root node?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the DataSource's XPath property to `/*/*`, which will skip the root node.